# Python find function selects one match per line

Tags: python, tkinter, text-editor

I am trying to make a simple text editor using python. I am now trying to make a find function. This is what I've got:

```
def Find():
    text = textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c').lower()
    input = simpledialog.askstring("Find", "Enter text to find...").lower()
    startindex = []
    endindex = []
    lines = 0
    if input in text:
        text = textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c').lower().splitlines()
        for var in text:
            character = text[lines].index(input)
            start = str(lines + 1) + '.' + str(character)
            startindex.append(start)
            end = str(lines + 1) + '.' + str(character + int(len(input)))
            endindex.append(end)
            textArea.tag_add('select', startindex[lines], endindex[lines])
            lines += 1

    textArea.tag_config('select', background = 'green')
```

This will succesfully highlight words that match the users input with a green background. But the problem is, that it only highlights the first match every line, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4jeq.png).

I want it to highlight *all* matches.

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/BkuXN5pk

Comment: Why not use the `re` module?

Comment: @I'L'I I'm a noob to python, could you explain what that is

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: @I'L'I How would I use that in this code

Comment: You wouldn't, you would use that and not this.

Comment: @I'L'I I read it, I tried it, I totally don't understand it.

Comment: Well show what you've tried and add it to your question, then someone can help you better.

Comment: I can't, because I don't even understand what I did, I didn't even know about the existence of re before, and I don't really learn to use it after reading about it once

Comment: @I'L'I Ron Norris' answer is much easier, and it also works, but I'll definitely look into the `re` module

Comment: @I'L'I: the re module is the wrong solution here since a) the OP is searching for a fixed string, and b) the OP is searching through a text widget which natively has the ability to search it's own text, and c) the OP is just learning and regular expressions are an advanced concept that will just get in the way in this particular problem.

Comment: @ConnerDassen: Yes, it's easier because they did all the work for you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommend using the text widget's built-in search capability. Shown using python3.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
textArea = Text(root)
textArea.grid()
textArea.tag_config('select', background = 'green')

f = open('mouse.py', 'r')
content = f.read()
f.close()
textArea.insert(END, content)

def Find(input):
    start = 1.0
    length = len(input)
    while 1:
        pos = textArea.search(input, start, END)
        if not pos:
            break
        end_tag = pos + '+' + str(length) + 'c'
        textArea.tag_add('select', pos, end_tag)
        start = pos + '+1c'

Find('display')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works, but now it is case-sensitive, how would I change that?

Comment: pos = textArea.search((input, start, END, nocase=True). I haven't tried it, but should be supported according to the docs.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how I could make it jump back to the beginning if it reaches the end?

Comment: @Conner Dassen Never mind, I already found the solution (The reason I want this is because I also made a find next function using the same method)